# Trying to read multiples address in i2c with raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, display, i2c

im trying to read the information from a TM1650 (is working with a 7 segment and 3 digits display) to a raspberry.
Firstable i was working with an arduino but after too many tryings y found that y cannot read diferents address value there at the same time(i need to read the adress value of 52,53 and 54 possition).
I have also an raspberry pi 4 and i wanted to know if there ir an code than can helpme to read the display data.
pd: the display is in to another board, that i have no program, thats what i wanna get the data.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone needs help with that in the future, the solution is to use threads, i used the library protothreads. Just remind not to use "delay" , try to use "millis".  (Arduino)